# Kernel of compositions

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $S\colon V\to V$ a linear operator. Show that
>
> - $\{0\}\subseteq\ker{S}\subseteq\ker{S^2}\subseteq\cdots.$
> - $\cdots\subseteq\text{Im}S^2\subseteq\text{Im}S\subseteq V.$

This looks very easy. But I'm with some problems to write the induction steps to proof this result...

- $\{0\}\subseteq\ker S$, because $S(0)=0$. If $x\in\ker S$, then $S(x)=0$ and $$S^2(x)=S(S(x))=S(0)=0\Longrightarrow x\in\ker S^2,$$ and we have $\ker S\subseteq\ker S^2$. But now, we need to proof that for any $\Bbb{N}\ni n\ge2$ we have that $\ker S^{n-1}\subset\ker S^n$. In my notes, I'm taking the induction hypothesis "$P(n)\colon \ker S^{n-1}\subseteq\ker S^n$". Assuming $P(n)$ as true for all $n\le k$, we need to show that $P(k+1)$ is true, that is, $\ker S^k\subseteq\ker S^{k+1}$. Let $x\in\ker S^k$ ($S^k(x)=0$), then $$S^{k+1}(x)=S(S^k(x))=S(0)=0.$$ But looks like I neither use the induction hypothesis.

It looks weird.

Comment: Maybe this link can help you, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3191294/demonstration-by-induction-without-using-the-induction-hypothesis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: you don't need to use induction. Prove the following two facts and with an appropriate instantiation of $T$ you are done:
$$\ker (T) \subseteq \ker(S \circ T)\\
\mbox{im}(S \circ T) \subseteq \mbox{im}(S)$$